# run a matlab function from Julia

Tags: matlab, julia

I am trying to use a custom matlab function in julia but I am getting an error.

I tried to do the following (https://github.com/JuliaInterop/MATLAB.jl)

```
mat"""

function [result] = run(x_pos, y_pos)

result = x_pos + y_pos;

end

"""
```

but I am getting this error:

> Error: Function definition not supported in this context. Create functions in code file.
>
> Unrecognized function or variable 'x_pos'.
>
> end;
> |
> Error: Illegal use of reserved keyword "end".

How can I use a custom matlab function in julia?

Comment: The error message says “Create functions in code file.” Have you tried that?

Comment: No, I don't know what is meant by that.

Comment: In MATLAB you cannot define a function by directly running that bit of code. You define a function by creating a file with a `.m` extension, containing that bit of code. The name of the file will be the name of the function. See [the docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html). You're better off just running the code `result = x_pos + y_pos;`, without trying to define a function around it. None of the examples in the page you link use the `function` keyword in MATLAB code.

Comment: Hey Chris! Thanks a lot for your answer! A short question: if I would run only the code result = a +b in the mat"""...""" mode - how would I return the value of result to Julia? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I guess `@mget` will do that: https://github.com/JuliaInterop/MATLAB.jl#mget-and-mput -- But there seem to be other options for running MATLAB code directly assigning into Julia variables: https://github.com/JuliaInterop/MATLAB.jl#the-mat-custom-string-literal